# Display image using xml

Tags: xml, image, windows-phone

I am trying to make simple task that display all image using xml. But i can't that task completely. Please help me...
**My xaml code:**

```
<ScrollViewer>
            <ListBox x:Name="imglist" Loaded="imglist_Loaded">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Width="160" Height="160"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

My xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Image ImageUrl = "C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/Butterfly.jpg"/>

  <Image   ImageUrl="C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/Desert.jpg"/>

  <Image    ImageUrl="C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/Field.jpg"/>
<images>

  <Image ImageUrl = "C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/Butterfly.jpg"/>

  <Image   ImageUrl="C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/Desert.jpg"/>
</images>
```

**Manipage.xaml.cs**:

```
private void imglist_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = XElement.Load("Authors.xml");
            var authors = from var in element.Descendants("Image")
                          select new images
                          {
                              ImageUrl = GetImage(var.Attribute("ImageUrl").Value)
                          };
            imglist.ItemsSource = authors;
        }

        private ImageSource GetImage(string p)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(p, UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

**class file:**

```
public class images
{
    public ImageSource ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see this link it has sample xml in it http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-use-xml-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

Check the paths in your XML file. `C:/Users/USER 1/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/pinchimage/pinchimage/` doesn't exist on your phone/emulator. You should be supplying either a URI to an image resource or content file within your app package, or a URL to an image on the internet. IIRC, for images in isolated storage, you'll need to broker them manually (although I may be wrong about that).